# Blindfolded and disoriented near the Great Wall of China

Tags: geometry

You are blindfolded and disoriented, standing exactly 1 mile from the Great Wall of China. How far must you walk to find the wall?

Assume the earth is flat and the Great Wall is infinitely long and straight.

Comment: I've seen an equivalent question before involving a swimmer or fisherman who is lost at sea and needs to find the shore.

Comment: do you know you are exactly away 1 miles from the Great wall?

Comment: How capable are we at moving?  Can I walk in a straight line for a half mile and know that I've walked a half mile?  Am I able to rotate to within the degree?

Comment: lateral thinking: 0 miles. Who says you need to walk, I can also crawl my way to the wall :P

Comment: if the lateral thinking tag was here people would go ham and throw random stuff like : take off what blinds you and rush to the wall... Let lateral away from that post :D

Comment: @RiddlerNewComer that is not lateral thinking, that is a  common sense

Comment: @IvoBeckers The answer where you commented on one's final direction being parallel to the wall was deleted, so I am responding here. The wall can only be EXACTLY parallel to your final direction if you have travelled EXACTLY perpendicular towards the wall for your first 1 mile travel in any direction - but then you find the wall. The reason for this is because you travel 1 PI in a circle after the 1 mile in a direction. Does this make sense?

Comment: @SpiritFryer, that's only true if you walk straight after the half circle but he walked 45 degrees inward. There's a good reason he deleted the answer and that's because I was right

Comment: @IvoBeckers Deleted reply comment as I was wrong. I only looked at the case where we get further from the wall in the circle part. If you rotate inwards in a case where you get closer to the wall towards the end of the circle part, then you run the risk of rotating to a path that runs parallel or even away from the wall.

Comment: @Oray I added the word "exactly" for clarification.

Comment: In the end, the researchers concluded, without any gadgetry, visual cues or other directional aids, humans have trouble moving too far from where they started. “[O]n average, people will not travel more than 330 feet (100 meters) from their starting point when using only body cues to guide their walking direction, regardless of how long they walk,” they write. “Without the use of an external directional reference, humans (like any animal) are not able to maintain a fixed course.” (http://healthland.time.com/2009/08/21) - a very cruel puzzle.

Comment: @dshin I that still doesn't answer whether or not you know that you are exactly 1 mile away. If you don't know this the answer becomes very different. But the fact that you accepted an answer that uses that fact I believe implies that you know it.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\arcsec}{arcsec}$

For each possible orientation of the wall (relative to some arbitrary initial orientation), the point on the wall closest to our starting point is a distance $1$ away.  The collection of the closest points for all possible orientations of the wall form a circle of radius $1$ around our starting point.

If we move a distance $r>1$ away from the initial point, we intersect two orientations of the wall that are an angle $\theta$ apart.  In order to reach that point we must have crossed all of the orientations in that angle.  In the figure below on the left, those "explored" points are marked by a magenta line.

[image]

By trigonometry we can show that $\theta = 2\arcsec r$.  If we traverse the path shown on the right side of the above figure, we travel a worst-case distance of:

$$
r + r(2\pi - \theta) \\
r + 2r(\pi - \arcsec r)
$$

This distance is minimized when $r\approx 1.04356$ for a worst-case distance of $6.99528$, an improvement of about $3.95\%$

However, looking at the figure we can immediately see that the majority of the large circular arc is "wasted" distance.  Only the ends contribute to additional "explored" points.  If we shrink-wrap the rest of the path around the unit circle, we get the following path:

[image]

The worst-case distance of this path is:

$$
r + 2\sqrt{r^2-1} + (2\pi - 2\theta) \\
r + 2\left(\sqrt{r^2-1} + \pi - 2\arcsec r\right)
$$

This happens to be minimized for $r = \sqrt{\frac{15-\sqrt{33}}{6}} \approx 1.24200$ (not the distance shown in the figure), for a worst-case distance of:

$$
\sqrt{\frac{9+\sqrt{33}}{2}}+4\arctan
   \sqrt{\frac{9+\sqrt{33}}{8}}
\approx 6.45891
$$

an improvement of $11.32\%$.

### Update

Thanks to Michael Seifert for pointing out that we can do better by letting the radii of the start and end be different, in which case we have the distance:

$$
r_1 + \sqrt{r_1^2-1} + \sqrt{r_2^2-1} + 2\pi - \theta_1 - \theta_2 \\
r_1 + \sqrt{r_1^2-1} + \sqrt{r_2^2-1} + 2\pi - \arcsec r_1 - \arcsec r_2
$$

Which is minimized by $r_1=2/\sqrt{3},\ r_2=\sqrt{2}$ (with $\theta_1=\pi/3,\ \theta_2=\pi/2$):

[image]

(Because of the nice angles, this picture is exactly to scale.)  The worst-case distance here is simply

$$
\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} + \frac{2\pi}{3} + \frac{\pi}{2} + 1 \\
= 1 + \sqrt{3} + \frac{7\pi}{6}
$$

(a $12.16\%$ improvement.)

Comment: This is excellent. I was about to start working on other angles, but see you've done it already. Slightly surprising

Comment: This can be further improved by allowing the distance you initially walk away from the origin (call it $r_1$) to be different from your final distance from the origin (call it $r_2$.)  The total distance is then $r_1 + \sqrt{r_1^2 - 1} + \sqrt{r_2^2 - 1} + 2\pi - 2 \arcsec r_1 - 2 \arcsec r_2$, which is minimized when $r_1 = 2/\sqrt{3}$ and $r_2 = \sqrt{2}$.  Total distance traveled is $1 + \sqrt{3} + 7 \pi/6 \approx 6.39724.$

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I don't follow. At which point do you deviate from the path in the shrink-wrap diagram?

Comment: @SpiritFryer:  I don't walk out as far initially, and then I wrap around the circle a bit further before leaving it on a tangent line.  I'll work up a diagram and post it as an answer.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Ah, I see. Yes, a diagram would be very helpful!

Comment: Nice work. $1+\sqrt{3} + \frac{7\pi}{6}$ is indeed optimal. The proof of optimality is extremely difficult, so I'll excuse you guys from providing one. :)

Comment: Note that the bottom-right point in the new path is the vertex of a hexagon that circumscribes the circle, while the following point is at the center of one of the edges of this same hexagon.

Comment: @dshin:  Do you know of a reference for proving the optimality?  I'd be curious to see it.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert My friend, a Harvard math PhD, took 5 years to finally come up with one. The proof is 8 dense pages of mathematics. I can ask him for permission to post it publicly, or perhaps I can send it to you privately?

Comment: @dshin: If he's comfortable posting it publicly, I'd love to take a look;  but if not, I understand completely.

Comment: According to [this paper](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Ford/Finch645-654.pdf) (see page 650), it was proved in 1980 [here](http://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/130395/files/PPN378850199_0035__0_0.pdf) (written in French).

Comment: @f'' Fascinating. Thanks for the link. Never knew this was a problem that was given significant consideration by professional mathematicians. It's fascinating that the optimal solution to the general problem of reaching some boundary is unknown for some very simple cases (like reaching the boundary of an equilateral triangle from an unknown point in its interior).

Comment: @MichaelSeifert My friend graciously posted [his solution](http://www.math.utah.edu/~tliu/great-wall-of-shin.pdf) on his webpage.

Answer (score 14):

If the angle between the possible wall and the initial line is $x$ (the angle between the diagonal line and the bottom line in the diagram below), then the distance travelled is $1+(\pi/2+2x)+1/tan(x)+1/sin(x)$.

Gratifyingly this gives a slightly improved answer of $2+3\pi/2\approx6.7124$ for my first attempt (because you can drop down straight rather than complete the circle), where $x=\pi/2$.

It also gives my second attempt for $x=\pi/4$ (answer $2+\sqrt{2}+\pi\approx6.5558$).

Throwing the expression into [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%2Fdx%281%2Bpi%2F2%2B2x%2B1%2Ftan%28x%29%2B1%2Fsin%28x%29%29%3D0), shows that a minimum occurs at $\pi/3$.  This gives a value of $1+\sqrt{3}+7\pi/6\approx6.397$

---

Old new upper bound: $2+\sqrt{2}+\pi$ as per diagram:

[image: Walk near the wall]

---

(Old upper bound: $2\pi+1$ miles. Walk 1 mile in any direction and then walk is a circle of radius 1, centred at your starting point. )

Comment: You can save a bit by walking straight one unit instead of the last quarter circle.

Comment: Would someone who's blindfolded (or even not) be able to walk in a perfect circle with such a huge radius? I'm not sure if this is in the scope of the question, though.

Comment: there is shorter upper bound

Comment: @dpwilson - I suppose the blinfolded person could be standing next to a metal stake firmly anchored into the ground with a very light and strong rope/cord attached to it that measures exactly 1 mile. (or he could have that in a backpack and attach it himself) - from there he could use that to precisely walk in a circle around the stake with only a slight margin of error, provided he constantly keeps his weight against the cord to keep it from dragging on the ground.

Comment: I think it's intended that the person has perfect control over their walking, otherwise there is no solution you can propose that doesn't introduce margins of error based on the person's ability. Can you walk *exactly* one mile, can you turn exactly N degrees, can you even walk in a perfectly straight line?

Comment: So with @xnor's observation the upper bound is 2π/3 + 2 miles (~6.7124). Which is about 0.5708 miles shorter than 2π + 1 (~7.2832). I might edit with a diagram when I get home.

Comment: With the little drawings, I just realized that if we walk more than one mile, we can skip some of the angles knowing that we can still reach the wall. The question is what would be the perfect distance and how many degrees to skip.

Comment: I made a typo in my previous comment. It's meant to read 3π/2 + 2 miles for the upper bound with xnor's method. The approximation is correct, since I had noticed my mistake after I typed in the first approximation, and then only fixed the approximation.

Comment: @ndefontenay You do save angles, but according to my (possibly faulty) maths, you don't save travelled distance. Using xnor's improved version of Dr Xorile's method, with a circle of radius 1 mi we travel 3/4ths of the circumference (arc of length 3π/2 mi), and we also travel 1 mi out and 1 mi towards the wall (total distance = ~6.7123 mi). For a circle of radius 2 mi, in worst case we travel at angle of π/6 towards the wall (angle between wall and path). For the same method, we would travel 7/12ths of the circumference, plus 3 mi (2 out and 1 towards the wall), which sums to ~10.3304 mi.

Comment: Now that @Dr Xorile has edited his answer I see that my calculations were incorrect. Very nice diagram by the way.

Answer (score 6):

I would like to present this non-rigorous but hopefully more intuitive explanation for the optimal path. (The technique used here was very helpful for working on [Oray's variant with two people](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/25819/).)

The first part of [2012rcampion's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/25538/) explains that we should go as far out as some tangent $l$, before going around the circle to get back to $l$ on the other side. Call the starting point $A$ and the circle $O$. Then the problem is this:

> Find the shortest path that comes from $A$, touches $l$, then goes around the circle and touches $l$ again.

It won't change which path is shortest if we turn around at the end and go all the way back:

> Find the shortest path that comes from $A$, touches $l$, then goes around the circle and touches $l$ again, and then goes back around the circle to $l$ and then $A$.

Now, if we reflect the entire diagram over $l$, we get this:

[image: 1]]

Instead of having our path touch $l$ and go back, we can have it switch sides every time instead, which won't change the length because it's just a reflection. So now the problem is this:

> Find the shortest path from point $A$ that goes around circle $O^\prime$, then around circle $O$, then goes to point $A^\prime$.

Anyone should be able to do that (imagine putting a string from $A$ around the circles to $A^\prime$ and pulling it tight):

[image: 2]]

And now if we only look at the part of the diagram above $l$, there's the answer without any calculations.

Answer (score 2):

"...standing exactly 1 mile from the Great Wall of China. How far must you walk to find the wall?"

You **must** walk 1 mile.  If you go the wrong way then you will end up walking further.  If you don't walk that far you can't reach it.

Comment: A sock drawer contains 5 pairs of sockets. How many socks must you pull out to get a matching pair?

Comment: @TracyCramer `must` is intended in the sense of what is the distance you must travel to be **sure** you reached the wall

Comment: @dshin why do you keep so many sockets opened my good man? You should clean up after your code that keeps socket connections opened

Comment: @njzk2 - I understand and accept that it's not the answer he was looking for - I answered somewhat in jest but didn't expect down votes for justified, accurate but not accepted answer. ;)  I'll delete if more people object.

Comment: @dshin - at least 2.  More if those two don't match. ;)  If they're folded together then 2.  If they're like mine and all white, then ... 2.  ;)  hehe

Comment: @dshin: Two, all mine are currently the same

Comment: @Patrice Do the upvoters of your comment know the inside joke? :)

Answer (score 0):

@DrXorile is clos to the answer. Mine isn't an answer either but here's some food for thoughts

I wanted to picture it. It looks like it.

If we take 360 individuals, all starting at the center of the circle and each at a different angle, only one will find the wall.

That's a 0.27% chance of finding the wall if you walk eaxtly one mile. 
If you need to reach the wall for your survival, you're dead.

Also imagine the guy who started just one degree slightly off, extend his hands  and the wall is just 2 inches further, then starts over in the wrong direction.

[image]

Walking more than one mile means we could increase our chances of reaching the wall at slightly off angle.

[image]

But then again, this could happen:

[image]

Comment: they could all miss the wall. to guarantee a hit you'd technically need infinite individuals

Comment: @Slepz you mean if they were to pick an angle at random or if they each pick one angle?

Comment: no I mean a circle is actually just an infinite number of points radius distance from the centre. We arbitrarily divide it into 360 degrees, but since a line tangent to a circle only touches at one point out of the infinite points you'd need infinite people. your .27% chance should be 0% because 360 / infinity = 0

Comment: @Slepz I had a feeling you were talking about the circle definition ^^. You're right but humans aren't infinitely small though. So our arbitrary degree measurement should do the job for this.

Comment: if we're going with real world, pi miles / average human arm span would be the probability. which is about 1/2000 or 0.05%

Comment: @Slepz You outmath me!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34560/discussion-between-ndefontenay-and-slepz).